# Additional Charge for Gift message option in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using **Magento 1.9**. I added `Gift options` via

`System->Configuration->Sales->sales->Gift Options`

and set `Allow Gift Messages` for Order Items to `YES`. Now in front end while checkout there is Gift Message form and I can provide Gift messages here.

But I need to charge Additional amount for `Gift Messages` (I think most of e-commerce website they charge additional amount for Gift messages) . But here it seems free. How can I provide `additional charge for Gift message`. Is there any settings for this in `magento`?

Please help me..Any help is really appreciable..